# React navigation 5 access navigation with class components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am currently migrating to react-navigation 5 (from react-navigation 4). My problem is that I am using class components and cannot access this.props.navigation, how do I pass the navigation to my class components and access it in my components.

My App.tsx looks like this:

```js
    export default function App(props:any) {

       const Stack = createStackNavigator();

        return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="CreateUserScreen" component={CreateUserScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>


        );
    }
```

And my pages looks like this:

```js
    interface ILoginScreenProps {
      navigation:any
    }

    interface ILoginScreenState {
      email: string
      password: string
      rememberlogin: boolean
      //navigation: any
    }

    class LoginScreen extends React.Component<ILoginScreenProps,ILoginScreenState> {
      gotoCreateUser = () => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.navigate('Createuser', {});
      }
      render() {
        return ( rendering stuff.. );
      }
    }
```

I know it can be done functional, but I would currently like to keep it as class components.
I get the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'navigation.navigate')

Comment: If you have a class component you should still be able to call it like this: this.props.navigation.navigate("Screenname") without problems. It works like this for me! for example set this to a buttons onpress and you should get navigated to the screen without any problems.

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Comment: Mh thats weird can you show the button that calls your gotoCreateUser? because the way it is witten should be correct. And if the button calls the function like this: onPress={this.gotoCreateUser} it should work

Comment: For the button i use:  <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={[{ opacity: 0.6 }, styles.button]} onPress={this.gotoCreateUser}>
              <Text >Create user</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>

Comment: In gotoCreateUser you have to call navigation.navigate("CreateUserScreen"). Try this and tell me what you get

Comment: Found the error, was not calling App properly, thank you very much for your help @yesIamFaded. Could you create an answer :)

Comment: alright no worries man - gl

Comment: Is there any correct solution for it? @user2579529 can you update your code to see how it is working?